# Drupal Question regarding automating the installation script

Tags: docker, jenkins, drupal, docker-compose

Right now I have a Jenkinsfile that is building a docker-compose.yml file which installs drupal, mariadb, and nginx.  Also the volume on the docker compose file is persistent.  In the Jenkinsfile, I have 2 steps, a docker-compose up and down.

I was wondering if there is a way in drupal, to automate the installation process in the beginning (where it asks you the language, database, and profile).  I am trying to have it, so developers will not see that screen every time after running a docker-compose down.

Sorry, I am fairly new to drupal so this might have a simple solution.

I have tried changing some settings in settings.php, however I am only able to populate the database.

Comment: Show a minimal code/configuration example of your current setup.

Comment: stages {
        stage('Cleanup') {
            steps {
               sh 'docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down || true'
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
           steps {
                sh "docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: FROM drupal:8.6.3-fpm-alpine

# Dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache \
 curl \
 git \
 vim \
 wget \
 mysql-client

# Install Composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
 php composer-setup.php && \
 php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
 mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Workdir set
WORKDIR /var/www

COPY cms /var/www

RUN composer install

Comment: sorry not sure how to maintain the spaces in the text for the comment section

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Drush or Drupal Console to execute the Drupal install? You can then execute

```
docker-compose exec WEBAPP ./vendor/bin/drush si --yes
```

You'll end up with a site installed and admin/admin as the login.